# Multilevel menu administration using js drag an drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu, backend

I'm looking for some input on a certain element of a project I'm developing. I want to include multilevel menus that easily manageable in the back end. I really like the structure wordpress uses in their back end to let users create menu's intuitively by dragging the menu items around. I'm looking for a bit of guidance with the multilevel part. I have made sortable lists before using jquery ui, but I'm a bit lost on the multilevel functionality (the js part)

I'd appreciate any input (plugins, examples, concepts) on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) is a plugin designed to do this. It's a good bet that there are others -- try searching the [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/).